# Adding custom toolbar to jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

How do I add custom toolbar to jqgrid.

Why I need this:
Instead of default filter toolbar I would like to introduce toolbar (Custom search options, not like editoptions:..) in my current project.

How do I implement it instead of using default filter toolbar

Answer (score 0):

The searching functionality have [many options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config) (like `searchoptions`) which are different from `editoptions`. The method [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) use the options and have many additional possibilities of customization, for example `beforeSearch` callback function. You don't describe your existing requirements, but I recommend you to examine the existing functionality of the searching toolbar more exactly before you will try to implement your own one.

If you do need implement your own custom toolbar, you can use [toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option of jqGrid to add an empty bar above or below of the grid. You will be full responsible for the filling of the content of the toolbar.

Comment: My client want functionality like Excel, I'll make use of those functionalities of searchOptions. but the UI will be more like EXCEL.    Example: giving a drop down like control which will have option buttons of corresponding column data (unique values) and few more options

Comment: @KK: What exactly you mean under "more like EXCEL"?

Comment: functionality will be of searchOptions only but the UI will be more like Excel as I described above.

Comment: @KK: You can modify the existing fields of jqGrid filter bar inside of `dataInit`. For example you can connect to edit fields jQuery UI Autocomplete or you can connect to drop down any jQuery drop down plugin which support the functionality which you need. Inside of `beforeSearch` you can modify in any way the data from `postData` parameter of jqGrid. So the modified data will be used for the filtering.

Comment: Your flow of events is nice to handle my situation and it is perfect.   Constraints for me My data will be coming dynamically and I need to place select boxes in drop down and even need to add scrollbar to that dropdown. Please guide me.

Comment: @KK: I am not sure that I understand you correct, but you can use `dataUrl` to get the list of options dynamically and can do additional customization inside of `buildSelect` which will be called in the `success` callback of the corresponding `$.ajax` request.